# How-to get chars represented by a range of ASCII values of a specific charset?

Tags: java, character-encoding

What I'm trying to do is generate an array of chars that represent certain ASCII values in a certain ISO/IEC charset. Let's say, if I'm intersted in ASCII values 211-217 of ISO/IEC 8859-7 charset then the result should be { Σ, Τ, Υ, Φ, Χ, Ψ, Ω }. I tried this:

```
for (int i = 211; i <= 217; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf((char)i));
}
```

But the results are based on the default system charset.

Comment: Note: ASCII only goes up to 127. You mean the code points of ISO-8859-7 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert individual character codes in particular encoding to `char`s directly, therefore you need to use `byte[]` to `String` conversion instead. Since ISO-8859-7 is a single-byte encoding, each character code corresponds to one `byte`:

```
Charset cs = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-7");
for (int i = 211; i <= 217; i++) {
    String s = new String(new byte[] { (byte) i }, cs)
    System.out.println(
        String.format("Character %s, codepoint %04X", s, (int) s.charAt(0)));
}
```

**EDIT:** Using the output format given above you can make sure that Unicode code points are decoded correctly, as specified by [ISO-8859-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7). If you still see `?`s instead of characters, it's a problem with output - your console doesn't support these characters.

Check a result of `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` - it should be some kind of Unicode (`UTF-8`, etc). If you run your code from IDE check its configuration for console encoding settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't totally clear. I think what you mean is that you have ISO-8859-7–encoded characters, and you want to convert them to Java characters (which are UTF-16–encoded Unicode points).

In that case, try this:

```
byte[] encoded = new byte[7];
for (int e = 211; e <= 217; ++e) 
  encoded[e - 211] = (byte) e;
String s = new String(encoded, "ISO-8859-7");
for (int idx = 0; idx < s.length(); ++idx) 
  System.out.println(s.charAt(idx));
```

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Works on mine, maybe your terminal doesn't support the font?